# How to stop tomcat from processing request after certain time?

Tags: java, tomcat, timeout

My tomcat server keeps processing some requests for more than 10 minutes. I stopped client which had triggered those requests but then also tomcat keeps processing those requests.

I have tried different settings for `connectionTimeout` property in `server.xml` file of tomcat but it is not working.

I would like to know how to configure tomcat such that tomcat kills/ stops processing requests which take longer than certain time like 10 seconds or 1 minute, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [The Apache Tomcat Connector - Generic HowTo
Timeouts](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/timeouts.html)

> JK can also use a timeout on request replies. This timeout does not
>   measure the full processing time of the response. Instead it controls,
>   how much time between consecutive response packets is allowed.
>
> In most cases, this is what one actually wants. Consider for example
>   long running downloads. You would not be able to set an effective
>   global reply timeout, because downloads could last for many minutes.
>   Most applications though have limited processing time before starting
>   to return the response. For those applications you could set an
>   explicit reply timeout. Applications that do not harmonise with reply
>   timeouts are batch type applications, data warehouse and reporting
>   applications which are expected to observe long processing times.
>
> **If JK aborts waiting for a response, because a reply timeout fired,
>   there is no way to stop processing on the backend. Although you free
>   processing resources in your web server, the request will continue to
>   run on the backend - without any way to send back a result once the
>   reply timeout fired.**